# Not calling react function outside of react scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-rails

I have a react class like below:

```
var AllMeals = React.createClass({

  ....

  concatMeal: function(new_meal) {
   newState = this.state.meals.concat(new_meal);
   this.setState({ meals: newState });
  },

  ....

});

module.exports = AllMeals
```

components.js looks like this

```
require('./constants')

....

window.AllMeals = require('./components/all_meals');

....
```

application.js looks like this

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require react_router
//= require react_router_ujs
//= require cable
//= require components
//= require_tree .
```

But when I call `concatMeal` function on `window.AllMeals` outside of react in a `meal.coffee` file like below I get `window.AllMeals.concatMeal is not a function`

```
App.meal = App.cable.subscriptions.create "MealChannel",
  received: (data) ->
    unless data.raw_html_for_meals_index.blank?
      window.AllMeals.concatMeal(data.raw_html_for_meals_index)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Class and instance.

Comment: @dfsq I'm new to jsx and reactjs, can you point me to how I can solve this problem. Thank you very much :)

Comment: `AllMeals` is class, not instance, so there is no method of course.

Comment: @dfsq Yeah that I know but my question is what is syntax for initiating AllMeals, I was under impression module.exports does exactly that.